# Difference of using `:` and `as` in Swift when specifying variable type in Swift?

Tags: variables, swift

Following a few different tutorials on Swift and noticed this difference. Are there cases where the two lines function differently, or is this more of a style preference?

```
var newString:NSString = "Test String"
```

and

```
var newString = "Test String" as NSString
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be an NSString at all? Just say `var newString = "Test String"` and stop.

Comment: @matt NSString has some other functionalities as swift strings. And as swift doesnt allow implicit typecasting, you have to do it yourself for example when a function only accepts NSStrings.

Comment: @Simon No you don't. Well, mostly you don't. There are very few situations where you can't pass a Swift string directly to Cocoa. Swift _does_ allow implicit typecast - of bridged types. And String-to-NSString is a bridged type.

Comment: Doesn't have to be NSString, was more of a question about the "as" and ":". Another simpler example:

    var newInt = 3.0 as Double

or

    var newInt:Double = 3.0

Comment: @Simon In fact, in his first example, `var newString:NSString = "Test String"`, there is _exactly_ such implicit typecasting! `"TestString"` starts out as a Swift String, but can be assigned directly, without casting, to an NSString variable.

Comment: Well, @TimothyTieu you wouldn't need to say that either because `3.0` is taken to be Double by default. So again you would just say `var newInt = 3.0`

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that in the first case, you declare the variable to be of type `NSString`, and hence it will be of type NSString, initialized with a string literal. (Either it's that the compiler performs an implicit conversion from the swift `String` type to `NSString`, or the literal itself is type-less – I'm not actually sure about this one.)

In the second case, you are not declaring the type of the variable explicitly. Instead, you perform an explicit conversion from the `String` literal to `NSString`, so the initializing expression itself has type `NSString`. Hence, type inference will tell the compiler that the type of the variable is also `NSString`.

The overall outcome of the two cases should be similar (if not identical modulo the cost of actual conversions, if any).

Answer (score 0):

There is no functional difference in this situation. It's merely the difference between a variable type explicitly declared in the variable declaration and a variable type implicitly inferred from the initial value. Either way, this variable gets a type, which is what matters.

(There are other situations, however, where the explicit declaration is necessary.)

Comment: And see my new Swift tutorial for more info about all that: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_declaration